# How To Pass Possibly Undefined Variables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, undefined

The usual rails sticky form functionality is not working. There are three checkboxes to be checked by default during sign-up. The following is the haml code for that.

```
= check_box_tag "subscription[news]", "news", ((!defined? params[:subscription][:news]) || (defined?(params[:subscription][:news]) && params[:subscription][:news]=='news') ? true : false)
= check_box_tag "subscription[recipes]", "recipes", ((!defined? params[:subscription][:recipes]) || (defined?(params[:subscription][:recipes]) && params[:subscription][:recipes]=='recipes') ? true : false)
= check_box_tag "subscription[exclusive]", "exclusive", ((!defined? params[:subscription][:exclusive]) || (defined?(params[:subscription][:exclusive]) && params[:subscription][:exclusive]=='exclusive') ? true : false)
```

The first part of each conditional is for page load with three checkboxes to be checked. If it's reloaded and we want to go sticky, we look at the other side of the `or` condition.
It seems there is a way to write a function in the helper to handle each of these three conditions. Is there any way to pass an undefined var into a function? Is `defined?` doing it? I can't find the declaration for that function.

The following function is what I would like to implement, but I'm not sure how to do this if the majority of the time, the param is not defined when passed.

```
def default_checked_sticky_form(param, value)
  ((!defined? param) || (defined?(param) && param==value) ? true : false)
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to do like this

```
params[:subscription] && params[:subscription][:news]
&& params[:subscription][:news]=='news'
```

**UPD:** you don't even need `? :`-operator